# WP_Query order by two values

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

m trying to make WP_Query to order by two different values, but i cant figure how to do this. Im trying to get events in one query by ending time. There is custom ending_date_time field in every event with datetime of value YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s. I need query to get values so first one is event that is closest to ending and so on, and if there is events that have ended, they come after those events that havent end yet.

With MySQL i would do this kind of thing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY event_endtime < NOW(), event_endtime ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what your looking for.

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'state_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => 'Wisconsin',
        ),
        'city_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 
        'city_clause' => 'ASC',
        'state_clause' => 'DESC',
    ),
) );
```

[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)